# Arrange values in array php / mysql

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I am exporting data from mysqli to google firebase DB. In firebase table one of the column named siteGeoCode (latitude and longitude) having values like [17.426083,78.439241] in array format. But in mysqli table two separate columns are there for latitude and longitude. I am trying to fetch records like below and converting those to array format.

```
$emp_array = array();
$sel_query = "select companyId,countryCode,createdBy,createdDat,`latitude`,`longitude`,siteName,`status` from customers limit 0,3";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqliConn,$sel_query);
while($sel_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $emp_array[]  = $sel_row;
    $lat_array['siteGeoCode'][0] = $sel_row['latitude'];
    $lat_array['siteGeoCode'][1] = $sel_row['longitude'];
    array_push($emp_array,$lat_array);
}
```

// output

```
[0] => Array
(
[companyId] => iArwfGLC1lE6x3lO24cb
[countryCode] => 91
[createdBy] => X54P6gVJ7dA4Fi2fjEmc
[createdDate] => 2019-08-20 00:58:08
[latitude] => 15.6070347
[longitude] => 79.6146273
[siteName] => Ongole
[status] => 1
)

[1] => Array
(
[siteGeoCode] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15.6070347
        [1] => 79.6146273
    )

)

[2] => Array
(
[companyId] => YPbhSLWQfAR6ThhszSAf
[countryCode] => 91
[createdBy] => iArwfGLC1lE6x3lO24cb
[createdDate] => 2019-09-10 22:37:08
[latitude] => 
[longitude] => 
[siteName] => Madhap
[status] => 
)

[3] => Array
(
[siteGeoCode] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
    )

)
```

but my desired output should be like below

```
[0] => Array
(
[companyId] => iArwfGLC1lE6x3lO24cb
[countryCode] => 91
[createdBy] => X54P6gVJ7dA4Fi2fjEmc
[createdDate] => 2019-08-20 00:58:08
[siteGeoPoint] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15.6070347
        [1] => 79.6146273
    )
[siteName] => Ongole
[status] => 1
)

[1] => Array
(
[companyId] => YPbhSLWQfAR6ThhszSAf
[countryCode] => 91
[createdBy] => iArwfGLC1lE6x3lO24cb
[createdDate] => 2019-09-10 22:37:08
[siteGeoPoint] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
    )
[siteName] => Madhap
[status] => 
)

How can I achieve this ? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to place the result of the latitude/longitude columns into the result grouped, do the manipulations to the row, then add it to your result set, abit like below.

```
$result = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    // group geo
    $row['siteGeoCode'] = [
        $row['latitude'],
        $row['longitude']
    ];
    // unset uneeded
    unset($row['latitude'], $row['longitude']);

    // place in result
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code.

```
$output_array = array();
while($sel_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {


$output_array[] = array(
          'companyId' => $sel_row['companyId'],
          'countryCode' => $sel_row['countryCode'],
          'createdBy' => $sel_row['createdBy'],
          'createdDate' => $sel_row['createdDate'],
          'siteGeoPoint' => array($sel_row['latitude'], $sel_row['longitude']),
          'siteName' => $sel_row['siteName'],
          'status' => $sel_row['status'],
        );
    }
print_r($output_array);
```

you can see the difference you've used the array and I did. From you output I guess you've print different arrays.

Hope the code get you desire result!

Comment: I got only one row of values. I have 3 rows in that table